# Dominant Balance with epsilon small

Tags: asymptotics, boundary-value-problem, perturbation-theory

Consider the boundary value problem $$ε
\frac{d^2y}{ dx^2}
+ (1 + x)
\frac{dy }{dx}
+ y = 0$$ subject to $y(0) = 0$, $y(1) = 1$, for $0 \le x \le 1$, $ε ≪ 1$.

By considering the rescaling $x = x_0 + ε^αX$, $y = Y$, for $X, Y = O(1)$, $α > 0$, show that a boundary layer is only possible at $x = 0$.

---

I am stuck on this question but I am mostly stuck on why we have to use dominant balance and how to use it in this.

We can turn the main equation into $$ε^{1-2\alpha }Y'' + ε^{-\alpha}Y'+x_0 ε^{-\alpha} Y'+ XY' +Y=0$$

Then the balance stuff comes in but I have tried reading my notes on it for ages but really don't understand how it work. I do know that we use it to find out what the form of our solution looks like.

Comment: Near $0$, the equation is approximately $\varepsilon y''+y'+y=0$ because $1+x \approx 1$. More precisely, you can rescale the domain and drop higher order terms to get $y''+y'=0$. Since the coefficient on $y'$ is positive, this undergoes exponential *decay*, which allows for matching with the outer solution which is assumed to be bounded.

Comment: Near $1$, the leading order equation after rescaling (using $z=(x-1)\varepsilon^\alpha$) is $y''+2y'=0$, because $1+x \approx 2$. This still has a positive coefficient on $y'$, so as you move to the *left* from $1$, this undergoes exponential *growth*, which can't be matched with the outer solution.

Comment: @Ian can you quickly show how the equation turns into the one i wrote please. Ive been trying it for long and i keep getting  $\varepsilon ^{1-\alpha} $ for the first term instead of whats written...

Comment: The equation after you switch to the inner variable near $x=0$ is $\varepsilon^{1-2\alpha}\frac{d^2 y}{dX^2}+(1+\varepsilon^\alpha X) \varepsilon^{-\alpha} \frac{dy}{dX}+y=0$. You get a factor of $\varepsilon^{-\alpha}$ for each derivative you take, because of the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $x=x_0+\epsilon^\alpha X$,
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dX}\frac{\mathrm dX}{\mathrm dx}=\epsilon^{-\alpha}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dX}$$
because $X=\epsilon^{-\alpha}(x-x_0)$. Therefore, the second derivative has a power of $\epsilon^{-2\alpha}$.

For your equation
$$\epsilon^{1-2\alpha }Y'' + \epsilon^{-\alpha}Y'+x_0 \epsilon^{-\alpha} Y'+ XY' +Y=0,$$
doing dominant balance means checking all the possible values of $\alpha $ that can balance two or more terms in the equation, and seeing which balances are consistent and dominant.

You have 3 different powers of $\epsilon$, $1-2\alpha$, $-\alpha$, and $0$. Thus, the balance is either $1-2\alpha=-\alpha$, $1-2\alpha=0$, or $-\alpha=0$.
The first balance is $\alpha=1$, the second is $\alpha=1/2$ and the third is $\alpha=0$.

Setting $\alpha=0$ is no scaling. This gives your outer solution.

Setting $\alpha=1/2$ is not dominant, because you have an $O(\epsilon^{-1/2})$ term ($Y'$) that dominates the rest of the equation.

$\alpha=1$ gives a dominant, consistent balance, with resulting equation
$$ Y''+(1+x_0)Y'=0. $$
Solving this equation will tell you what $x_0$ can or cannot be.

Comment: if we solve your equation we get $$Y_0=A_0+B_0e^{-(1+x_0)X}$$ If $x_0 =0$ then we would have $B_0e^{-X}$ which would blow up if $X \rightarrow -\infty$. Even if $0<x_0\leq 1$, then it would still blow up when $X \rightarrow -\infty$. This doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Since $0\leq x\leq1$, if $x_0=0$ then $0\leq X\leq 1/\epsilon$, so in the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow0$, you have to think of $X$ as ranging from $0$ to $\infty$, so blowing up as $X\rightarrow-\infty$ is not relevant, as this is not in the domain of the problem. If $x_0>0$, then you do have to consider what happens as $X\rightarrow-\infty$, and you do get blow-up. This is why you must have $x_0=0$.